SOSL query returns 0 results for criteria ending with ' s'
When I execute this query in the Developer Console:
FIND {searchterm} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Id)

I get a number of results, instantaneously (assuming the one or more products contain 'searchterm' in one of its fields)
But this query:
FIND {searchterm s} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Id)

will take a couple of seconds and then return 0 results (even though searchterm and s were shown in the results of the first query).
I tried it with other single characters that were also shown in the results, such as a d, but no problems there.
A colleague of mine offered the suggestion that {searchterm s} is being converted into something like {searchterm%20s}, which causes problems in the underlying Java software.
Does anyone recognize this problem? Any solutions?
Update 1: having seen Phil W's answer, I tried some more queries. These are the results:
FIND {searchterm and s} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Id)

0 results
FIND {searchterm or s} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Id)

250 results (which I believe is some kind of SOSL limit)
FIND {s searchterm} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Id)

6 results
FIND {s and searchterm} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Id)

6 results
FIND {s or searchterm} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Id)

250 results
FIND {s searchterm s} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Id)

0 results
When I look at all these results, my suspicions that something funny is going on are growing. I mean 'searchterm s' and 's searchterm' should return the same results, right? I am not using "" to enforce any specific order.
Update 2: to my surprise, the query
FIND {searchterm s} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Id)

gives the correct results in sandboxes. I notice that our production org has version Winter '25 Patch 11.12, and the sandboxes have version Winter '25 Patch 12.
So it looks like Salesforce has already fixed this bug on sandboxes.

This was indeed a bug (although I couldn't find any known issue for it) and it has been fixed with the release of version Winter '25 Patch 12.

As per the documentation:

The search engine splits record information separated by spaces or punctuation into separate tokens. The search engine returns accurate search results from searches in East Asian languages that don't include spaces between words using morphological tokenization.

Such multiple tokens are considered to have AND operators between them (most of the time; Articles, Documents and Solutions assume OR) so all of the defined terms must be found to constitute a match. Both words, searchterm and s, must be complete terms in the records being matched, unless you include (suffix) wildcards.
You can, of course, include quotes around the search term to prevent the space being used to delimit separate tokens, or you can explicitly provide operators between the tokens, such as searchterm OR s (noting that case is ignored on the operators and that if your searchterm or s values are in reality operator names this may be why you are having trouble).
In your case, I'm not sure why you get no results back, but use the above documentation link to explore how you can obtain the behaviour you need.

The article you refer to states: "Usually if an operator isn't specified, AND is the default operator. "

Ah, OK. I missed that. Will update.

I am pretty convinced that somewhere deep in Salesforce something is going wrong for SOSL queries of which the search term ends with ' s'.
In our org, user input is being used as input for the SOSL query (it was a user who discovered this behavior and I was able to track it down using raw SOSL queries in the Developer Console).
The, not very nice, work-around is to check in Apex code whether the user's input ends with ' s'. If so, strip it from the input and prefix the input with 's '.

I'd suggest you raise a case with Salesforce on this one then.

Alas, my company's support contract doesn't cover Developer Support.
